# Translate "I am the storm"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Can someone please help translate this "I am the storm". The context is
“The devil whispered in my ear, ‘You’re not strong enough to withstand the storm.’ Today I whispered in the devil’s ear, ‘I am the storm.’”

Much appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll shy away from a literal translation (which is a very post-Classical way of speaking) that the images show, and go with a more classical idiom:

> Ecce tempestas!

> Behold, the storm!

This works better if you imagine it in Roman comedy, where a character appears on stage and utters the line.

I should note that *tempestas* can mean something other than storm. *Procella* and *hiems* might be more specific, with the latter being a winter storm, but all three can and often do mean "a violent, rainy storm."

Answer (score 2):

I would translate this as:

> Ego tempestas sum.

Either the *ego* or the *sum* could be left out, but the *ego* is for emphasis (so you're not just saying, “I'm a storm”), and the *sum* is there because I like complete sentences.

In case you're getting a tattoo, you [won't be](https://d.facebook.com/autumnskyeart/photos/pcb.1373573676019674/1373573576019684/?type=3&source=49&__tn__=EH-R) [the first](https://www.instagram.com/p/B2iLQL9lYlo/?hl=de) ;-)

Comment: Thank you, not a tattoo, just a custom necklace for a lady veteran.